# Unable to scrape lyrics off using telegram bot hosted on heroku

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, telegram-bot

I have recently hosted a telegram bot on heroku and wrote a function that is able to get the top 5 most popular songs of an artist off musixmatch using beautiful soup. Initially, it was able to but now it does not. I tried running locally and is still able to return me results. These are my codes:

```
query = "hillsong"
   search_page = requests.get("https://www.musixmatch.com/search/{}/tracks".format(query),
                              headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
   soup = BeautifulSoup(search_page.content, 'html.parser')

   top_tracks = soup.find_all(class_="showArtist showCoverart", limit=5)
   output_top_tracks = "<b>Top search results on {}:</b>\n\n".format(query)
   for track in top_tracks:
       title = track.find("a", class_="title").get_text()
       artist = track.find("a", class_="artist").get_text()
       href = track.find("a", href=True)['href']
       # print(href)
       uuid = str(uuid4()).upper()[:4]
       output_top_tracks = output_top_tracks + " " + title + "\n" + " " + artist + "\n" + "/lyric3" + uuid + "\n\n"
```

Expected output:

```
 Faded
 Alan Walker
/lyric3A848

 Alone, Pt. II
 Alan Walker
/lyric38904

 All Falls Down
 Alan Walker
/lyric35DD4

 Sing Me to Sleep
 Alan Walker
/lyric3968D

 Lily
 Alan Walker
/lyric349BC
```

Error:

```
2020-07-21T13:21:52.827581+00:00 app[web.1]: song_title = best_result.find("a", class_="title").get_text()
2020-07-21T13:21:52.827582+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will print top 5 songs found on the page:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.musixmatch.com/search/hillsong/tracks'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

for t, s in list(zip(soup.select('.media-card-title'), soup.select('.media-card-subtitle')))[:5]:
    print(" " + t.text)
    print(" " + s.text)
    print(t.a['href'])
    print()
```

Prints:

```
 Oceans - Where Feet May Fail
 Hillsong UNITED
/lyrics/Hillsong-UNITED/Oceans-Where-Feet-May-Fail

 Hosanna
 Hillsong UNITED
/lyrics/Hillsong-UNITED/Hosanna

 What A Beautiful Name
 Hillsong Worship
/lyrics/Hillsong-Worship/What-a-Beautiful-Name

 Awake My Soul (with Tasha Cobbs Leonard)
 Hillsong Worship, Tasha Cobbs Leonard
/lyrics/Hillsong-Worship-Tasha-Cobbs-Leonard/Awake-My-Soul-with-Tasha-Cobbs-Leonard

 Who You Say I Am
 Hillsong Worship
/lyrics/Hillsong-Worship/Who-You-Say-I-Am
```